# ADODC retrieve indivisuals values into EditBox

Tags: c++, mfc

Is there a method to retrieve individual values from ADODC into an edit box

I tried the following way :-

m_edit1=m_adodc1.GetRecordset().GetField().GetItem("table1_names");

but got an error "binary '=' no conversion available .....

as I remember

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [retrieve the value of a field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `Value` property, you then need to call the `SetWindowText()` member function pof the [edit control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7yhsd2b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), like:

```
m_edit1.SetWindowText(m_adodc1.GetRecordset().GetField().GetItem("table1_names").Value());
```

EDIT: the value needs to be converted using the [_bstr_t](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class:

```
LPTSTR lpValue = (LPTSTR)(_bstr_t) m_adodc1.GetRecordset().GetField().GetItem("table1_names").Value();
m_edit1.SetWindowText(lpValue);
```

Comment: Edward ,, by the way , where can i specifies the table field that i want to retrieve data from ?

Comment: you need to specify parameters to the `GetRecordset()` and `GetField()` functions -- take a look at the MSDN artcle for the [Recordset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681510(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Fields Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676603(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I will give it a try ,, then inform you .

Comment: Edward , the informations above belongs to ADODB which is diferent than ADODC  ,,  is it ?

Comment: ADODC is just a data control where you can bind a recordset to a data source, whereas ADODB is a generalised class library. ADODC would be easier to use -- just look up the parameters to the `GetRecordset()` and `GetField()` functions in ADODC

Comment: Edward i tried the code above , the error is "SetTextWindow" doesnt accept parameter of type tagVARIANT  .

Comment: @SaeedBasrah : Edited my answer to convert from variant to LPTSTR

Comment: the compiling was ok
but the application breakdown
i think the problem is here GetItem("*table1_names*")
GetItem (*what to put here*)   ?

Comment: that would contain the name of a column in the selected table -- could you edit your question and post the updated statement?

Comment: ok i will , but may i ask you to make a simple project that working fine and contain the main ideas ? that would be much appreciated .

Comment: Sorry, i don't post complete solutions in SO -- why don't you make up a simple database with 1 table with 1 field and 1 row of data and post another question about how to access the data value? Do you really need to use ADODC or will any ADO with MFC ok?

Comment: Edward please check my post above .

Answer (score 0):

ADODC or nothing  ;)
however check the follwing :-

i made it ,,, partially !!
to inform you about my mdb file :-
its name (inventory.mdb)
it has one table (Stocks)
the fields are (StockName,StockID,...)
now i can extract values from only the "StockName" which its string values
by the following code in button click :-

```
   m_ado.SetRecordSource ("SELECT * FROM Stocks");
   m_ado.Refresh ();
   C_Recordset m_Record = m_ado.GetRecordset ();// this line can be omitted !

   COleVariant var1;
   var1.vt = VT_I2;
   var1.iVal = 1;
   COleVariant value = m_ado.GetRecordset().GetFields().GetItem(var1).GetValue ();
   m_edit = value.bstrVal;

    UpdateData (FALSE);
```

how to extract the other values such as "StockID" which its integer or any other fields ?

Comment: by using `var1.iVal = 0` -- this is the "index" of the column: zero = first, 1 = second, ...

Comment: then i have to make a suitable change as required for the data types  from Variant to the proper type                                    let me give it a try then back  .